# Remove white space when using conditional rendering on Visualforce component in Lightning view

Tags: visualforce, lightning, page-layout

I can't get rid of the white space above the Visualforce page that is embedded on my page layout. The Visualforce markup has conditional rendering depending on the user's display theme. The whitespace is only showing in Lightning, not in Classic (see screenshots).

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{! !isClassic}">
    <apex:slds />
</apex:outputPanel>
<div class="slds-scope">

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!isClassic}">
    <div style="font-size: 10;padding-left: 38%">
    Director's Time
    </div>

</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{! !isClassic}">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-m-top_none">
    Director's Time
    </div>

</apex:outputPanel>    

</div>
</apex:page>
```

[image: Classic]
[image: Lightning]

Comment: Hard to tell what whitespace you are talking about here

Answer (score 1):

I would restructure your page a bit to get rid of extra divs, may or may not solve your issue....

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!isClassic}">
    <div style="font-size: 10;padding-left: 38%">
    Director's Time
    </div>

</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{! !isClassic}" layout="block" styleClass="slds-scoped">
    <apex:slds />
    <div class="slds-grid slds-m-top_none">
    Director's Time
    </div>

</apex:outputPanel>    

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Tried this, but got no formatting, just Times New Roman. Tried switching the output panels so the Lightning markup appears first and added slds-scope to the div above Director's Time. Still seeing the white space above Director's Time text.

Comment: What is the markup for the stuff above it? I guess the slds has to be before the scoped div

Comment: Yes the first thing on the page after apex:page should be an output panel with nothing in it except <apex:slds />. This is according to documentation from Salesforce. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/workshop-lightning-programmatic/steps/programmatic-step-2

Comment: @KristyAnn - Still need to see the markup for the stuff above it. Did you use the console to inspect the generated markup to see what class/styles were adding the margin/padding

Comment: I don't have markup for the rest of the page, it's just the standard detail page.

Comment: @KristyAnn - Ahh so the rest is the standard SF stuff. Did you inspect the markup using the dev tools in the browser to see why there was whitespace. It would be helpful to understand what you need to do to fix it

Comment: I tried applying the style tags to my page but it didn't work...even if I take out all the style I still see the indent on the left and whitespace on the top.

Comment: I tested and moved text right below the <apex:slds /> tag and it was still indented.